# AVSpeechSynthesizer isSpeaking not working in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, avspeechsynthesizer

So after updating to Xcode 12.0.1 AVSpeechSynthesizer is now working on simulator (it hasn't been working for me for a while).  Now, the isSpeaking variable is always false regardless of whether the synthesizer is speaking.  I would like to trigger a change in my view as a function of whether the synthesizer is speaking.  Simple version below, any ideas?

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct ContentView: View {

var synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
var utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hello World")

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(synthesizer.isSpeaking ? "Speaking" : "Not Speaking")
        Button(action: {synthesizer.speak(utterance)}) {
            Text("Speak To Me")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just not updated in your case, because `synthesiser.isSpeaking` is not observable for SwiftUI. You have to use view model class and delegate callbacks to handle this state changes

Here is initial demo (you can add stop/pause/continue actions by yourself)

```
class SpeachViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {
    @Published var isSpeaking = false

    private var synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    override init() {
        super.init()
        synthesizer.delegate = self
    }

    deinit {
        synthesizer.delegate = nil
    }

    func speak(_ utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        self.synthesizer.speak(utterance)
    }

    // MARK: AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate
    internal func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didStart utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        self.isSpeaking = true
    }

    internal func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        self.isSpeaking = false
    }

    internal func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didPause utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        self.isSpeaking = false
    }

    internal func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didCancel utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        self.isSpeaking = false
    }

    internal func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didContinue utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        self.isSpeaking = true
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var vm = SpeachViewModel()
    var utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hello World")

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(vm.isSpeaking ? "Speaking" : "Not Speaking")
            Button(action: {vm.speak(utterance)}) {
                Text("Speak To Me")
            }
        }
    }
}
```